# Using a background image with an 'H' tag

Tags: image, background, width

I followed the answers to try to achieve a similar look to be found here [www.thexxcorporation.com](http://www.thexxcorporation.com)

The first header is using a shortcode (its a Wordpress site).

My problem is that the shortcodes don't reflect their actual styling setting, therefore, I'm trying to reproduce the look, but with my own sizes, images etc.

I've tried this:

```
h1:after
{
background:url(image path);/* apply your image here */
background-repeat:repeat-x;
content:" ";
position:absolute;
width:999em;
height:25px;
margin:10px 0 0 5px;
}
```

This, almost works, but has a problem.  The style relates to headers that are with a content div.  My other hears fit within the div fine (100% of the width of the div).

The above code results in the background image overflowing outside the content div it sits within.

So, how do I constrain it to the width of the div it sits within?

My page code looks like this:

```
<div id="main-content" class="clearfix">    
       <header id="page-heading">
           <div class="boxed">
              <h1>Test</h1> 
                    </div><!-- /boxed -->
    </header><!-- /page-heading -->


   <div id="home-content" class="clearfix boxed container">
    <article id="post" class="clearfix">
        <div class="entry clearfix fitvids">
            <h1>Test page for H1</h1>
        </div><!-- .entry .clearfix -->
    </article><!-- #post -->

    <aside id="sidebar">
    </aside><!-- /sidebar --></div><!-- #home-content -->

   <div class="clear"></div>
```

The containing divs are set with position:relative.

If I add position:relative to the h1:after - the background image disappears.

slightly baffled.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: I have tried changing the width parameter - this just results in the background image disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

the div it sits within should in relative position. add this style to the div

```
position:relative;
```

and the h1::after should have 100 percent width - don't use em. change the width to

```
width:100%;
```

hope this helps
cheers

Comment: Hi,Thanks for such a speedy response.